# PrimeFaces DataTable doesn't refresh on deleting a row

Tags: primefaces

Currently using primefaces 3.3 and want to refresh the datatable on removing an item from the list.

When I refresh the page, do see updated table, so the list is getting updated in java code.

Thanks for your time and help.

Please let me know where I am misktaken.

Here's the relevant code:

```
//in xhtml
<p:dataTable id="userConnections" var="connection" value="#{loginBean.userConnectionEmailList}"> 
<p:column> 
<h:outputText value="#{connection.email}" /> 
</p:column> 
<p:column> 
<p:commandButton id="deleteButton" icon="ui-icon-close" title="Delete" process="@this" action="#{loginBean.deleteConnectionAction}" update="userConnections">
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{connection}" target="#{loginBean.selectedUserConnection}"/>
</p:commandButton>
</p:column> 
</p:dataTable> 
// java code
public String deleteConnectionAction() {
System.out.println("###deleteConnectionAction ###" + selectedUserConnection.getEmail() );
userConnectionEmailList.remove(selectedUserConnection);
return "";
}
```

Comment: See if you see any javascript error using debugger in firefox.

Comment: This issue was resolved after updating to primefaces 3.5